# Avoid multiple try except block in python

Tags: python, exception

I want to handle few function calls using `try excpept` block. Is there any better and cleaner way to do it. My current flow is

```
def handle_exception():
    try:
        x()
    except Exception:
        print("Failed to init module x")
    try:
        y()
    except Exception:
        print("Failed to init module y")
    try:
        z()
    except Exception:
        print("Failed to init module z")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke the modules in a loop

```
def handle_exception():
    modules = x, y, z
    for module in modules:
        try:
            module()
        except Exception:
            print(f'Failed to init module {module.__name__}')
```

If you want to pass parameters as well you can use `dict` to store the data

```
def handle_exception():
    modules = {x: [1, 2], y: 'asd', z: 5}
    for module, params in modules.items():
        try:
            module(params)
        except Exception:
            print(f'Failed to init module {module.__name__}')
```

Comment: Thanks... This will really work. Is there any way to pass parameters in this as well? That will really be helpful.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi There is, see updated answer.